# Moulding shapes out of empty tags. Code explanation required

Tags: html, css, animation

I have been trying to figure out this piece of [CSS animation](http://codepen.io/daneden/pen/JFxAw/?editors=110) . 
From the markup you can see

```
<b class = "b switch"> </b>
```

and the applied css style to it is

```
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 36px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Though the CSS style specifies nothing about block display or width or height, the empty `<b>` tag still manages to curve itself into a round circle that fits perfectly into the div. How does that work ? I would really appreciate if someone threw some light on the usage of empty  `<i>` or `<b>` tags and mould them into different shapes .

Comment: it is border-radius which is giving a perfect fit into the div try to play with its value u will understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with which tag you're using.

If you specify `position: absolute`, a `width` and `height` of `auto` (which is the default), and all four of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`, the element will stretch to fit within those bounds.

Comment: @nashmaniac: Not quite; its offset container, which is the closest positioned ancestor.

Comment: Ok, if we ignore the border radius property. What bound is the .switch class fitting into? Because its square in shape (without border radius) , whereas its ancestor the .toggle(right?) class has a pill like shape .

Comment: @nashmaniac: Yes; `.toggle` is its offset parent.  All that matters from the parent is the bounding box; the parent's border radius is ignored.

Comment: if we ignore the .toggle class's border radius, its a rectangle . But the .switch class expands into square (with width and height set to default) . How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55321/discussion-between-nashmaniac-and-slaks).

Answer (score 2):

`position: absolute;` implies `display: block` for inline elements [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo), while `left` + `right` and `top` + `bottom` pairs set the dimensions according to the viewport (or closest positioned ancestor). BTW there IS `display:block` set for class `.b`.

So there's a 60 x 40px rectangle with position:absolute, and inside is another rectangle, also positioned absolutely by 2px from the top, left and bottom edge of its parent and 22px from the right. If you remove `border-radius: 36px` line it should become clear :)

Comment: it is not what he asked "the empty <b> tag still manages to curve itself into a round circle that fits perfectly into the div. How does that work ?" that was his question

Comment: border-radius is how you make a circle, but it doesn't explain why it works without `display:`, `width:` and `height:`, and the rounded element doesn't "fit" the div, these elements are overlaid with the smaller circle having a 2px offset on three sides and 22px offset on the fourth.

Comment: "BTW there IS display:block set for class .b" yeah I forgot to mention that in the question. But even if you remove that part where b is set to block, everything still works the same

Comment: @nashmaniac yes, it's not necessary for the reasons listed in my answer.